# Dont know why the below script would not crawl glassdoor.com

Tags: python-2.7, web-crawler

Dont know why the below python script would not crawl glassdoor.com website

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # documentation available at :` #www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/
from bs4 import NavigableString, Tag
import requests # To send http requests and access the page : docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/
import csv # To create the output csv file
import unicodedata # To work with the string encoding of the data

entries = []
entry = []
urlnumber = 1 # Give the page number to start with

while urlnumber<100: # Give the page number to end with

    #print type(urlnumber), urlnumber

    url = 'http://www.glassdoor.com/p%d' % (urlnumber,) #Give the url of the forum, excluding the page number in the hyperlink
    #print url


    try:
        r = requests.get(url, timeout = 10) #Sending a request to access the page
    except Exception,e:
        print e.message
        break

    if r.status_code == 200:
        data = r.text
    else:
        print str(r.status_code) + " " + url

    soup = BeautifulSoup(data) # Getting the page source into the soup
    for div in soup.find_all('div'):
        entry = []
        if(div.get('class') != None and div.get('class')[0] == 'Comment'): # A single post is referred to as a comment. Each comment is a block denoted in a div tag which has a class called comment. 
            ps = div.find_all('p') #gets all the tags called p to a variable ps
            aas = div.find_all('a') # gets all the tags called a to a variable aas
            spans = div.find_all('span') #
            times = div.find_all('time') # used to extract the time tage which gives the iDate of the post

            concat_str = ''
            for str in aas[1].contents: # prints the contents that is between the tag start and end
                if str != "<br>" or str != "<br/>": # This denotes breaks in post which we need to work around.
                    concat_str = (concat_str + ' '+ str.encode('iso-8859-1')).strip() # The encoding is because the format exracted is a unicode. We need a uniform structure to work with the strings.
            entry.append(concat_str)

            concat_str = ''
            for str in times[0].contents:
                if str != "<br>" or str != "<br/>":
                    concat_str = (concat_str + ' '+ str.encode('iso-8859-1')).strip()
            entry.append(concat_str)

            #print "-------------------------"
            for div in div.find_all('div'):
                if (div.get('class') != None and div.get('class')[0] == 'Message'): # Extracting the div tag witht the class attribute as message.
                    blockqoutes = []
                    x = div.get_text()
                    for bl in div.find_all('blockquote'):
                        blockqoutes.append(bl.get_text()) #Block quote is used to get the quote made by a person. get text helps to elimiate the hyperlinks and pulls out only the data. 
                        bl.decompose()


                    entry.append(div.get_text().replace("\n"," ").replace("<br/>","").encode('ascii','replace').encode('iso-8859-1'))


                    for bl in blockqoutes:
                        #print bl
                        entry.append(bl.replace("\n"," ").replace("<br/>","").encode('ascii','replace').encode('iso-8859-1'))

                #print entry
            entries.append(entry)

    urlnumber = urlnumber + 1 # increment so that we can extract the next page

with open('gd1.csv', 'w') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter= ',', lineterminator = '\n')
    writer.writerows(entries)
print "Wrote to gd1.csv"
```

I fixed some errors in your script, but I guess that it doesn't print anything because you only get 405(!)-pages!
Also your previous try/catch-block didn't print the error message. Was it on purpose?

Comment: it should create a file in your python folder in csv format....but the important qs is it is not able to crawl websites which it was designed to do....cant figure out why

Comment: Try the links you are generating in the browser. They don't work there either!

Comment: can you help suggest improvements?

Comment: I don't even know what these links should do or mean, so I can't really help!

Comment: Which links are talking about?